# Issue with cookies in AIR Simulator

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am building a FLex application in Flash Builder 4.7 that needs to access facebook.  However whenever I try to log in to facebook via the app on the AIR simulator I get a Cookies are not enabled in your browser error.

Driving me nuts and I can't find any documentation for the life of me.

Comment: How are you trying to login? AIR isn't a browser [for all intents and purposes].  I have no idea how it interacts with HTTPService calls that require cookies.

Comment: I'm using the GraphAPI_Mobile_1_8_1 to connect to facebook.  All I need is a feed of posts from a public user to display.  YouTube and Twitter have been done successfully already, however Facebook requires Access Tokens just to get the JSON feed.  In order to get the token the user needs to log in.  Unfortunately in the development environment I cannot pass the login to test the rest of the functionality.  I've seen videos where it works no problem, so I know it can be done in the AIR simulator

Comment: Also, to my understanding, I have manage sessions set to true, so the app should be managing sessions and not having to rely on cookies.  Am I mistaken on this presumption?

Comment: You may consider sharing some code.